# Inter-Domain iframe Content Access

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to communicate between iframes on different domains?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div>

<iframe id="tc" src="http://www.domain1.com/page1.html">
</iframe>


<iframe id="tf" src="http://www.domain2.com/page1.html">
</iframe>

</div>

<div>
<button onclick="tcget();">Click me</button>
<button onclick="tfget();">Click me</button>
</div>


<script>

function tcget()
{
   try
   {
       alert($('#tc').contents().find('body').html());
   }
   catch(err)
   {
       alert(err);
   }
}


function tfget()
{
   try
   {
       alert($('#tf').contents().find('body').html());
   }
   catch(err)
   {
       alert(err);
   }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to share content, from each iframe loaded into the same page.

I have looked into `window.postMessage` but this does not appear to be able to do it either. My app will be pulling statistics from each `iframe` for a Neural Net - I hope that it can be done, security wise it seems that its not something that can be done.

Comment: "I have looked into window.postMessage but this does not appear to be able to do it either." — It is as close as you can get.

Comment: Just a pointer, missing closing quote in `$('#tc)`